# Getting Unable to persist data entity, Error while commiting the transaction

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery, tridion-storage-extension, tridion-deploy-extension

I successfully managed to write deployer extension as well as storage extension.

And below are the logs which I took from core logs, which shows everything is loaded perfectly!!

```
2013-01-08 11:30:19,759 INFO  BundleConfigurationLoader - Added 'PublishAction' for storage 'persistence' with 'com.tridion.storage.dao.JPAPublishActionDAO'.

2013-01-08 11:30:38,259 DEBUG JPAPublishActionDAO - Constructor of JPAPublishActionDAO- storageId:searchdb
2013-01-08 11:30:38,259 DEBUG JPAPublishActionDAO - Constructor of JPAPublishActionDAO- entityManagerFactory:true
2013-01-08 11:30:38,259 DEBUG JPAPublishActionDAO - Constructor of JPAPublishActionDAO- storageName:PublishAction

2013-01-08 11:19:38,400 INFO  Module - No TransformProcessor configured, will not transform files before deployment for module com.tridion.custom.extensions.SearchPageDeployer
2013-01-08 11:30:38,400 DEBUG SearchPageDeployer - Constructor of SearchPageDeployer //This is my PageDeployer Constructor


2013-01-08 11:30:38,744 DEBUG SearchPageDeployer - Called processPage from SearchPageDeployer //This is my process Page of pagedeployer class

2013-01-08 11:30:38,572 DEBUG SearchPageDeployer - SearchPageDeployer Called processItem
2013-01-08 11:30:38,572 DEBUG StorageManagerFactory - Default storage provider has caching set to: false
2013-01-08 11:30:38,572 DEBUG StorageManagerFactory - Loaded following dao Properties[publication=0, typeMapping=PublishAction, storageId=searchdb, cached=false] for publication/typeMapping/itemExtension: 0 / PublishAction / null
2013-01-08 11:30:38,572 DEBUG StorageManagerFactory - Loading a non cached DAO for publicationId/typeMapping/itemExtension: 0 / PublishAction / null
2013-01-08 11:30:38,572 DEBUG StorageManagerFactory - Wrapping DAO's, currently 0 wrappers installed
2013-01-08 11:30:38,572 INFO  JPAPublishActionDAO - Entering Method: JPAPublishActionDAO.PublishAction.store
2013-01-08 11:40:33,228 ERROR SearchPageDeployer - SearchPageDeployer - Exception occurred com.tridion.broker.StorageException: Unable to persist data entity, Error while commiting the transaction, Error while commiting the transaction
```

Now when I am trying to store the data in my table I am getting **"Exception occurred com.tridion.broker.StorageException: Unable to persist data entity, Error while commiting the transaction, Error while commiting the transaction"**

is this any issue with my Entity class or something I am missing.

EDIT: After the enable logger level "ON" in logback xml.

I got below exception in core files:

```
2013-01-08 14:42:10,713 DEBUG SQL - insert into AUTN_ITEMS (ACTION, FLAG, ITEM_TYPE, LAST_PUBLISHED_DATE, PUBLICATION_ID, SCHEMA_ID, TCMURI, URL, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2013-01-08 14:42:10,728 DEBUG AbstractBatcher - about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
2013-01-08 14:42:10,744 DEBUG JDBCExceptionReporter - could not insert: [com.tridion.storage.dao.PublishAction] [insert into AUTN_ITEMS (ACTION, FLAG, ITEM_TYPE, LAST_PUBLISHED_DATE, PUBLICATION_ID, SCHEMA_ID, TCMURI, URL, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'AUTN_ITEMS' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi there. Is that the only error you're seeing? Can you check for a stacktrace in your log file? If you don's see more error information then maybe you can turn on root logging (root level="DEBUG" in the logback.xml).

Comment: @Sea, yes this is the only exception I am getting, I have already enabled level ="DEBUG", after decompiling the JPABaseDAO, I saw that exception is generated in its  public <T extends BaseEntity> T create(T itemToCreate) throws StorageException method, don't know what could be reason as Entity is according to my SQL table, if you want I can post my entity code also

Comment: Probably it's something small which is not in sync between your entity and your table. To be able to see this better just make sure you have this in your logback.xml: <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="rollingCoreLog"/>
    </root>

Comment: No idea what could be I can see the data before storing bean, please see the log taken before I am going to save the data.
[PublishAction:id=0,action=PUBLISH,url=/english/test/test.aspx,tcmuri=tcm:233-192242-64,last_published_date=Tue Jan 08 14:42:10 GST 2013,item_type=64,schema_id=null,flag=null]

Comment: Can you make sure you have your column ID defined as identity, that you have the schema_id and flag allowed to contain null values and that you do not have other columns in your database that are marked as not null?

Comment: yes my column ID is defined as identity as well as primary key, it seems something related to "IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF." did you have any experience to handle this using hibernate

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22381/discussion-between-manoj-singh-and-sea-gull)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is suggesting that your ID column is not defined correctly as an identity or that you're trying to manually set a value to the autogenerated value in this column.
Hope this helps.

Regards,
Daniel.

Comment: @sea_gull..thanks I am also thinking same, however I can see in my code that I am not setting any value for ID, as at SQL level I have created simple table with ID column as Identity (seeding 1 and incrementing 1), is the problem at SQL level or at my Entity Class level where Hibernate is automatically trying to fire this query.

Comment: @ManojSingh can you please update the question with your model class?

Answer (score 0):

The ID column should be set to auto increment at db level. Have a look at my original article on sdltridionworld for an example http://www.sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/extending-content-delivery-storage-sdltridion-2011-1.aspx

"For SQL Server, column ID is defined as IDENTITY(1,1), so it increments automatically by one, without us having to specify value.

For Oracle, column ID needs to be defined using a Sequence (that generates the values), like this:
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_PUBLISH_ACTIONS MAXVALUE 999999999999999 CYCLE START WITH 1
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PUBLISH_ACTIONS_KEY
BEFORE INSERT ON PUBLISH_ACTIONS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :new.ID IS NULL THEN
    SELECT SEQ_PUBLISH_ACTIONS.NEXTVAL INTO :new.ID FROM DUAL;
  END IF;
END;
/
"

Comment: I have already done this, however it seems some issues with my Entity Class, I will post my entity class code for your reference!!

Answer (score 0):

Above issue was in my Entity Class, I need to add below annotations for my identity column.

```
@Id
@Column(name = "ID", unique=true,updatable=false,insertable=false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
```

Please do suggest if any changes are required.

Thanks